# How to make the file shareable using google drive api

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, drive, google-picker, google-api-js-client

I am trying to get the file using google drive api, by default the file is not shareable i want to make it shareable.

Here is my code:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
        // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
            // Replace with your own Browser API key, or your own key.
            var developerKey = 'XXXXXXXXXX_ff_NX66eb-XXXXXXXXXXX';

            // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
            var clientId = "XXXXXXXXXX-hs4ujaro5sc3d0g8qndtcq2tl279cfm1.apps.googleusercontent.com"

            // Replace with your own App ID. (Its the first number in your Client ID)
            var appId = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
            var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

            var pickerApiLoaded = false;
            var oauthToken;

                  $scope.addGoogleDriveFile = function() {
                    gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
                     gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad}); 
                    gapi.client.setApiKey(developerKey);     
                      }

        function onAuthApiLoad() {
                         window.gapi.auth.authorize(
                             {
                               'client_id': clientId,
                               'scope': scope,
                               'immediate': false
                             },
                             handleAuthResult);
                       }

                        function onPickerApiLoad() {
                          pickerApiLoaded = true;
                          createPicker();
                        }

                        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                          if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                            oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
                            createPicker();
                          }
                        }

                        // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
                        function createPicker() {
                          if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
                            var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
                            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                                .setAppId(appId)
                                .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                                .addView(view)
                                .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                                .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                                .build();
                             picker.setVisible(true);
                          }
                        }

                    // A simple callback implementation.
                    function pickerCallback(data) {
                      if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                          console.log(data);
                       gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2').then(function() {
                            var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                            'fileId': data.docs[0].id
                          });   
                           request.execute(function(resp) {
                             console.log(resp);
                          }); 
               });

                      }
                    }
```

I am getting the following response:-

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc",
 "etag": "\"rCKCAyesbPCaBxGt0eDJcEBQNUI/MTQ1ODgxNDU0MDg2NA\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc",
 "webContentLink": "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc&export=download",
 "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc/view?usp=drivesdk",
 "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_12_pdf_list.png",
 "thumbnailLink": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/iriNEeCbpP3OfCxntpc7sK7Dok03tcBJ86X4Be_sFgLXXG1Ta8b2WOM6pF6sEpS8ytaMvA
=s220",
 "title": "POTSS-2012.pdf",
 "mimeType": "application/pdf",
 "labels": {
  "starred": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "trashed": false,
  "restricted": false,
  "viewed": true
 },
 "createdDate": "2016-03-24T09:57:00.978Z",
 "modifiedDate": "2016-03-24T10:15:40.864Z",
 "modifiedByMeDate": "2016-03-24T09:57:00.978Z",
 "lastViewedByMeDate": "2016-03-24T09:57:00.978Z",
 "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
 "version": "130",
 "parents": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#parentReference",
   "id": "0AGTb9btqdPGHUk9PVA",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc/parents/0AGTb9btqdPGHUk9PVA"
,
   "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AGTb9btqdPGHUk9PVA",
   "isRoot": true
  }
 ],
 "downloadUrl": "https://doc-0o-3g-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/79n10ihd7kdei03rpq502qv5437nv33f
/b6p7kupn55cuqeqq8l0d9vc1orf4bkiv/1458813600000/07489391032112366212/07489391032112366212/0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc
?e=download&gd=true",
 "userPermission": {
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"rCKCAyesbPCaBxGt0eDJcEBQNUI/QKpDIyepJ3z6YHq0L3ksgvrZLSo\"",
  "id": "me",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc/permissions/me"
,
  "role": "owner",
  "type": "user"
 },
 "originalFilename": "POTSS-2012.pdf",
 "fileExtension": "pdf",
 "md5Checksum": "5b60cd94d0c0647c8828a60b8ce7efe4",
 "fileSize": "519097",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "519097",
 "ownerNames": [
  "xxxxx IT"
 ],
 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "xxxx IT",
   "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
   "permissionId": "07489391032112366212",
   "emailAddress": "it%xxxx .com@xxxxx.com"
  }
 ],
 "lastModifyingUserName": "xxxxx IT",
 "lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "xxxx IT",
  "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
  "permissionId": "07489391032112366212",
  "emailAddress": "it%xxxx.com@xxxx.com"
 },
 "editable": true,
 "copyable": true,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "shared": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "appDataContents": false,
 "headRevisionId": "0B2Tb9btqdPGHT0pGV1FRRis0MmlJVmZsOE5uMU5UK2FNR0g0PQ",
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ]
}
```

Here i want to change **"shared": true** Instead of **"shared": false**

How can i change its permission?

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

@arun you may want to read more about [Permission resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions) in Drive API. For **"shared"** to be **true**, each file permission needs to specifies a `role`, `type`, and `email address or domain`. As an owner of the file (Docs, Sheets, etc.), you will need to provide the appropriate permission to be set to.

Here is an example, using the [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) (I recommend using [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk))

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/permissions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
 
{
 "role": "reader",
 "type": "user",
 "emailAddress": "xxxxxxxx@xxx.com"
}
```

Response from the Drive [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?fields=appProperties%2CfileExtension%2Ckind%2CmimeType%2Cshared&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

 
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
 "shared": true
}
```

However, if you are unable to switch to the Drive v3, you can still use the [Permission.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) from Drive v2 to do the job. Hope this helpful and good luck!

Comment: I already done this but its not working for me ....Its always return "shared": false. I tries this link https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create#try-it and give it the permission according to your answer but its not working.

Comment: @arun can you provide a bit more information as to what you meant by changing the "shared" to true? the "Shared" property is not *writable*, so you won't be able to just modify the value. One additional question, are you an owner of that specific file?

Comment: how can I get the value of "YOUR_API_KEY", is it the token for authorization?

Comment: @LiangWang It works even without API KEY, just use token in the query header, like that: Authorization: Bearer  [Token]

Answer (score 1):

The Quickest way to obtain the preview of the file would be to append `/preview` at the end of Alternate link.

Like so [`https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc/preview`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Tb9btqdPGHeDl2NU5mYXRIaGc/preview)

You can then share that link to others.

Found this [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it) when i was testing out api requests on the drive api.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I was having was I did not enable the Google Drive API in my Google developer console and I did not load the 'client' library in order for gapi.client.request() to work properly with Google Picker.

Below is a working example for a user to click a "share" button, authorize permission to their Google Drive, select multiple images or videos from the Picker modal, and return the file hyperlinks with 'anyone with the hyperlink can view' permissions.

Prerequisites:

- [Setup your credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) in the Google developer console

  - Obtain your developer ID, client ID, and app ID
- Enable both the [Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) and Drive APIs in the developer console

The javascript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  // The API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
  var developerKey = '#####';

  // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
  var clientId = "####"

  // App ID. (Its the first number in your Client ID)
  var appId = "####";

  // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
  var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

  var pickerApiLoaded = false;
  var oauthToken;

  // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
  function onApiLoad() {
    gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
    gapi.load('picker:client', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
  }

  function onAuthApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': clientId,
        'scope': scope,
        'immediate': false
      },
      handleAuthResult);
  }

  function onPickerApiLoad() {
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
  }

  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
      createPicker();
    }
  }

  // Create and render a Picker object
  function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
      var view1 = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES_AND_VIDEOS)
        .setIncludeFolders(true)
        .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
        .addView(view1)
        .setAppId(appId)
        .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
        .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }

  // A simple callback implementation.
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    var doc = "";
    var fileID = "";
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var gdurl = "";
      var type = "anyone";
      var role = "reader";
      for(var i = 0; i < data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS].length; i++){
        doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][i];
        gdurl = gdurl + " " + doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        
        //change the file permissions to share with anyone with the link
        fileID = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var request1 = gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + fileID + '/permissions',
          'method': 'POST',
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
          },
          'body':{
            'role': role,
            'type': type
          }
        });
        request1.execute(function(resp) {
          console.log(resp);
        });
      }
      // Form and display the message with hyperlinks included
      var message = 'Google Drive media link(s): ' + gdurl;
      alert('Success! Here are the hyperlinks for anyone to view: ' + message);
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Then the button to call everything in the HTML:

```html
<button onclick="onApiLoad()">Share via Google Drive</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer under this question did it for me:
[make folder shared google drive api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538269/make-folder-shared-google-drive-api-v3)

I applied it to 'file' rather than folder, made the type 'anyone' and role 'reader' - seems to be the equivalent of making the file shared.