# How can I share GoogleDrive's file/folder using JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-drive-api

Using GoogleDrive JavaScript API I was being able to develop a sharing file/folder with another Gmail user.

I'm using [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing) example but I get the follwing error:

> `Uncaught Reference Error: 'drive' is not defined`.

A screenshot of the error is [here](http://prntscr.com/fqca5z).

Do you have any solution to share file/folder using GoogleDrive JavaScript API?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198386/how-to-make-the-file-shareable-using-google-drive-api), for **"shared"** to be **true**, each file permission needs to specifies a `role`, `type`, and `email address` or `domain`. As an owner of the file (Docs, Sheets, etc.), you will need to provide the appropriate [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions) to be set to.

Additional reference: [make folder shared google drive api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538269/make-folder-shared-google-drive-api-v3)