# make a file shareable using drive api in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-drive-api

In my mobile application I am using Drive API to upload an file to the google drive. It works well. But it uploads all the files as **not shareable**. I want to make this **shareable**.

Here is my code in kotlin

```
    // upload a file in to google drive
    fun uploadFile(localFile: java.io.File, mimeType: String?, folderId: String?): Task<Any>? {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, Callable<Any> { // Retrieve the metadata as a File object.
            val root: List<String> = folderId?.let { listOf(it) } ?: listOf("root")
            val metadata = File()
                    .setParents(root)
                    .setMimeType(mimeType)
                    .setName(localFile.name)
            val fileContent = FileContent(mimeType, localFile)
            val fileMeta = mDriveService.files().create(
                    metadata,
                    fileContent
                ).execute()
            val googleDriveFileHolder = GoogleDriveFileHolder()
            googleDriveFileHolder.setId(fileMeta.id)
            googleDriveFileHolder.setName(fileMeta.name)
            googleDriveFileHolder
        })
    }
```

There is a answer in js [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198386/how-to-make-the-file-shareable-using-google-drive-api) but I dont understand how to do it inside my function. Please help.